# How to show "thumbnail" instead of "swatch image"?

Tags: magento2, product-images, color-swatches, gallery-image

Anyone knows how to show thumbnail image instead of swatch?

I already have setup swatch role for the whole catalog and I'm looking for a solution without modifing image role.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your theme `view.xml`
in `app/design/frontend/<Vender>/<theme>/etc/view.xml`

```xml
...
<image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
    <width>210</width>
    <height>210</height>
</image>
...
```

Ref: https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-change-swatch-image-size/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is for the size of the images. I want to show "thumbnail" instead of "swatch_image" and I already have tried to modify <image id="swatch_image" type="thumbnail"> but it's don't works.